# Loop through all Controls and Clear desired

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Hello I'm trying to find the desired label in controls of my panel1. All my labels are named like "lbl0", "lbl1" and so on.

So I tried to loop through all of these labels until I find the right one:

```
Control DelCon(string Name)
    {
        foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
            if (c.Name == Name)
            {
               c.Controls.Clear(); // this should delete the control
            }


        return null;
    }
```

But at the end even when the `c.Name == Name` the control is not deleted.

Might someone help me solve this out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast fix to your  code above

```
Control DelCon(string Name)
{
    Control toRemove;
    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
         if (c.Name == Name)
         {
            toRemove = c;
            break;
         }
    }
    if(toRemove != null)
        panel1.Controls.Remove(toRemove); 
    return null;
}
```

Your original code remove ALL the child controls (if any) from the control that you found inside the panel collection of child controls. 
As a side note, you cant remove an element from a collection while you are looping over that collection. So a fast fix is to copy the reference of the control to remove and exit from the loop and remove the control (if found) after exiting from the loop

The code above could be shortened using Linq

```
Control toRemove = panel1.Controls.Where(x => x.Name == Name).SingleOrDefault();
if(toRemove != null)
    panel1.Controls.Remove(toRemove);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any loop. Your panel has a `Controls` holding collection of controls it contains. Just pass in the control name to get the control:

```
public Control DelCon(string name)
{
    Control c = panel1.Controls[name];
    panel1.Controls.RemoveByKey(name);//Using RemoveByKey is the best choice
    return c;
}
```